# Caliburn binding exception

Tags: c#, wpftoolkit, caliburn.micro, simple-injector

Let me explain my problem. Please excuse me for the long question.
Here it goes.

I have a View (**BusyProviderView**)

```
<Grid>
    <xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="aaa" IsBusy="{Binding IsRunning}" >
        <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock Name="Message"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

Which has **View model:**

```
    public class BusyProviderViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IBusyProvider
{
//two properties with INPC, Message and IsRunning
}
```

Again I have a **Shell view**

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmTest.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ShellView" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Height="25" x:Name="Run">Run</Button>
    <ContentControl x:Name="BusyProvider"/>
</Grid>
```

Which has a **view model**

```
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShellViewModel
{
    private IBusyProvider busyProvider;

    public ShellViewModel(IBusyProvider busy)
    {
        this.BusyProvider = busy;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IResult> Run()
    {
        yield return new DummyOperation(this.BusyProvider);
    }

    public IBusyProvider BusyProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return this.busyProvider;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, this.busyProvider))
            {
                return;
            }
            this.busyProvider = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.BusyProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

**DummyOperation** Looks

```
public class DummyOperation : IResult
{
    public IBusyProvider Provider { get; set; }

    public DummyOperation(IBusyProvider provider)
    {
        Provider = provider;
    }

    public void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (a, b) =>
            {
                Provider.IsRunning = true;
                Provider.Message = "Working";
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                Provider.Message = "Stopping";
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                Provider.IsRunning = false;
            };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (a, b) =>
            { Completed(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs()); };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed;
}
```

Finally I have **BootStrapper**

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShellViewModel>
{
    private Container container;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.container = new Container();
        this.container.Register<IWindowManager,WindowManager>();
        this.container.Register<IShellViewModel,ShellViewModel>();
        this.container.Register<IBusyProvider, BusyProviderViewModel>();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {

        return this.container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }


    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    }
    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        this.container.Verify();
    }
}
```

Looks Like I have set everything,
But When I try to run it throws an exception.
[image]

I am sure the problem is causing by

```
 <DataTemplate>
            <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock Name="Message"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

> cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}

Once I remove above statement the program runs without a crash but no binding.

If you look at the Image,

```
 protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {

        return this.container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }
```

serviceType is passed as a **NULL**, and key is **"Please Wait...."** ,
Where that comes from ??

Comment: You're setting datacontext for your view to viewmodel right?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not help you with this, but... Did you know that with C# 5.0 you can change the `NotifyOfPropertyChange` method to the following: `void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")`. This saves you from having to pass the `() => this.BusyProvider` lambda (expression tree) in. (see [here](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/18/what-else-is-new-in-c-5/)).

Comment: Can you try `cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding}"` instead of `cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"`?

Comment: @nemesv I am so sorry, that does not work!

Comment: @Oleg, I have not set datacontext by myself.

Comment: So it was the datacontext problem :)

Comment: @Oleg, That could be, Too little knowledge on WPF and caliburn :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems by default the [Extended Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/)'s `BusyIndicator` uses the string `"Please Wait...."` for the `BusyContent`. So inside the `DataTemplate` the `DataContext` will be the above mentioned string and this causes the confusion and exception in Caliburn.

To fix it you need to set the `BusyContent` on the `BusyIndicator` to the current `DataContext` and it will work:

```
<xctk:BusyIndicator x:Name="aaa" IsBusy="{Binding IsRunning}" 
                                 BusyContent="{Binding}" >
    <xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}">
                <TextBlock Name="Message"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xctk:BusyIndicator.BusyContentTemplate>
</xctk:BusyIndicator>
```

Comment: Sweet! What else could I say. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think Oleg is right though, you cannot use conventions in a DataTemplate using Caliburn (CaliburnMicro you can). From the [Documentation - Other Things to Know](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Conventions)

> Other Things To Know
>   On all platforms, conventions cannot by applied to the contents of a DataTemplate. This is a current limitation of the Xaml templating system. I have asked Microsoft to fix this, but I doubt they will respond. As a result, in order to have Binding and Action conventions applied to your DataTemplate, you must add a Bind.Model="{Binding}" attached property to the root element inside the DataTemplate. This provides the necessary hook for Caliburn.Micro to apply its conventions each time a UI is instantiated from a DataTemplate.

Comment: Based on the stacktrace and provided code samples OP uses `Caliburn.Micro` just the question is tagged with caliburn

Comment: @leon, Grid is the root element for the template. I even tried <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/> But with the same result

Comment: Conventions can be used in template if the `Bind.Model="{Binding}"` is present.